# node.js - How to chain download many images from a url

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, download

Basically, I want to download a large amount of images from an image service. I have a very large JSON object with all of the URLs (~500 or so) in that JSON object. I tried a few npm image downlader packages as well as some other code that did each image downloading all at the same time; however, about 50% of the downloaded images had data loss while downloaded (a large portion of the image was transparent when viewed). How can I download each image, one after another (waiting until the last one is complete before starting the next) to avoid the data loss?

Edit: here is the relevant code, using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```
var download = function(url, dest, callback){                                                         

    request.get(url)                                                                                  
        .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)} )                                                   
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))                                                                 
        .on('close', callback);                                                                           

};                                                                                                    

links.forEach( function(str) {                                                                                                                                                  
        var filename =  str[0].split('/').pop() + '.jpeg';                                            
        console.log(filename);                                                                        
        console.log('Downloading ' + filename);                                                       
        download(str[0], filename, function(){console.log('Finished Downloading ' + filename)});
});
```

My `links` JSON looks like this:

```
[["link.one.com/image-jpeg"], ["link.two.com/image-jpeg"]]
```

Comment: Whatever library you are using to download must be having a callback to be invoked when download is complete. You can use that to prevent parallel-downloading. Please add some relevant code to your question so that we can help.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have included the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so first thing first :

I really do not believe that downloading those 500+ images will all start at once. The V8 engine (kind of the `nodejs` code executor) actually manages a reasonable number of threads and reuse them to do the stuff. So, it wont create "lots of" new threads, but will wait for other threads to get done.

Now, even if it was all starting at once, I don't think the files would get damaged. I the files were getting corrupt, you wouldn't have been able to open those files.

So, I am pretty sure the problem with the images is not what you think.

Now, for the original question, and to test if I am wrong, you can try to download those files in a sequence like this :

```
var recursiveDowload = function (urlArray, nameArray, i) {
    if (i < urlArray.length) {
        request.get(urlArray[i])                                                                                  
            .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)} )                                                   
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(nameArray[i]))                                                                 
            .on('close', function () { recursiveDownload (urlArray, nameArrya, i+1); });
    }
}
recursiveDownload(allUrlArrya, allNameArray, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing large number of downloads, try [Aria2c](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aria2). Use [Aria2 documentations](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/) for further details.